# Please help me to draw this diagram in LaTeX

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic

[image]

Please help me to draw this diagram in LaTeX

Comment: `tikz-cd` package

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Answer (score 11):

The picture you show was created with Xy-pic. A modern replacement is `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
Y \arrow[r,hook] \arrow[d,swap,"T(f)"] &
\mathcal{H}(D^{\infty}(Y)) \arrow[r,"h"] \arrow[d,swap,"\widehat{T(f)}"]
  \arrow[dr,swap,dashed,"\widehat{f}\circ h"] &
\mathcal{H}(D^{\infty}(X)) \arrow[d,"\widehat{f}"] &
X \arrow[l,hook'] \arrow[d,"f"]
\\
\mathbb{R} & \mathbb{R} & \mathbb{R} & \mathbb{R}
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

The `hook'` arrow type reverses the side of the hook. The rest should be almost self explanatory: you build a matrix, specifying the arrows with `d` for “down”, `r` for “right” and so on. The key `swap` refers to the position of the label (default is on the left of the arrow, going from tail to tip).

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to expand on why `tikz-cd` is a modern improvement on `xypic`? I don't know anything about their advantages and disadvantages relative to each other, and would love to learn.

Comment: @ArunDebray `tikz-cd` is based on the powerful TikZ-PGF graphic creation package. Not only this, the syntax for commutative diagrams is far superior to Xy-pic's.

Answer (score 5):

A `pstricks-add` solution, that can be compiled with `pdflatex` if the `-shell-escape` switch is enabled (TeX Live, MacTeX) or the `--enable-write18` switch (MiKTeX).

```
\documentclass[pdf]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
\[%
\begin{psmatrix}
%%% Matrix nodes
Y & \mathcal{H}\smash{(D^{\infty}(Y))} & \mathcal{H}\smash{(D^{\infty}(X))} & X \\
\mathbb{R} & \mathbb{R} & \mathbb{R} & \mathbb{R}
%%% Arrows
\psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0.2, nodesep=2pt, shortput=nab, hookwidth=-4pt, hooklength=4pt}
\ncline{1,1}{2,1}_{T(f)}\ncline[arrows = H->]{1,1}{1,2}
\ncline{1,2}{2,2}_{\widehat{T(f)}}\ncline{1,2}{1,3}^{h}
\ncline{1,3}{2,3}_{\widehat{f}}
\ncline{1,4}{2,4}_{f}\ncline[arrows=H->, hookwidth=4pt]{1,4}{1,3}
\ncline[linestyle=dashed, nodesepA=6pt]{1,2}{2,3}\nbput[labelsep=0pt, npos=0.4]{\widehat{f}\circ h}
\end{psmatrix}
\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Svend Tveskæg: Sorry, I forgot my editor configuration displays `∞` (and saves `\infty`, naturally). Corrected.  Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: Thanks again! WinEdt is powerful, but it can be inconvenient sometimes…

Comment: Emacs + AUCTeX is also powerful ... and doesn't have any inconveniences. `;)`

Comment: Unfortunately, I never could get used to emacs — although it can make a good coffee.