# How can I draw this double diagram in Latex?

Tags: diagrams

How can I draw this diagram in Latex?

[image]

Comment: This could help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/319722/14757 https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211696/14757

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `tikz-cd` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
  G & B \arrow[l,"\psi"above]\arrow[d]\arrow[r,"g"] & C \\
  & B/f(A) \arrow[lu,"\psi'"] \arrow[ru,"g'"below,"\simeq"above] &
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]